# PostGIS query to split a polygon by n other polygons

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to write a PostGIS query to do the following:

[image]

1. Get polygons from a table that overlap geometry A above (in this case, B and C).
2. Get the intersecting area.
3. Split the intersecting area by the overlapping polygons (in this case, returning D and E).

In this case there are 2 overlapping polygons, but I need to support an arbitrary number.

I'm stuck on how to get started with this. I know I can use `ST_Intersects` to get the intersecting polygons and `ST_Intersection` to get the overlapping area, but I'm not sure the splitting will work. It looks like `ST_Split` only accepts two geometries Can anyone think of how I could get this to work with *n* polygons?

Comment: Why is the question off-topic ? Please comment when close-voting.

Comment: still on hold? what's unclear about this?

Comment: Who knows. A couple of the close votes come from people with a bit of a robo-review reputation, so hardly surprising. The question is extremely straightforward, but not unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Table `a` holds your polygon "A" and Table `b` holds your Polygons "B" and "C", the following should return the two records with polygons "D" and "E":

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom)
FROM a JOIN b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

---

If you want to receive only a single (multi-)polygon per `a.fid`, you can add `st_union` and `group by a.fid`:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom))
FROM a JOIN b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.fid;
```